# Using decorated helper methods in same engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm decorating a couple of helper methods in another engine:

```
Backend::PathHelper.module_eval do

  def spent_appable_points_path(paramz = {})
    send("spent_#{appable_type}_points_path", appable, paramz)
  end      

  def earned_appable_points_path(paramz = {})
    send("earned_#{appable_type}_points_path", appable, paramz)
  end

end
```

Using these two methods inside my views in the Backend engine works fine. But when I try to use these two methods in the same engine I am decorating it in, they are not available.

```
Backend::PathHelper.public_instance_methods # doesn't return them
```

What would the proper DRY way to be able to use these two methods in the same engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created another module and just injected it like so:

```
Backend::PathHelper.module_eval do

  include MyOtherEngine::PathHelper

end
```